# GDB Character Set of Argument in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I've disassemble in GDB and in inside of the sscanf function I get:

```
    at vfscanf.c:603
_IO_vsscanf (string=string@entry=0x804b760 "1 \\233 200", 
    format=format@entry=0x804a21e "%d %c %d", 
    args=args@entry=0xbffff0a8 "\304\360\377\277\277\360\377\277\300\360\377\277\224\361\377\277\310\360\377\277\201\222\004\\\351") at iovsscanf.c:47
```

I'm trying to get the information in args but I'm not sure how to translate that string to something readable.  What I'm really trying to get is the addresses that sscanf is saving to.  I assume these addresses are represented in this string.  This is what I got when looking up the charset:

```
(gdb) show charset
The host character set is "auto; currently ANSI_X3.4-1968".
The target character set is "auto; currently ANSI_X3.4-1968".
The target wide character set is "auto; currently UTF-32".
```

I'm using Linux, IA-32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $'\304\360\377\277\277\360\377\277\300\360\377\277\224\361\377\277\310\360\377\277\201\222\004\\\351'|od -t x4  

0000000 bffff0c4 bffff0bf bffff0c0 bffff194
0000020 bffff0c8 5c049281 00000ae9
0000032
```

Then you can inspect the contents by:

```
print *(int*)(0xbffff0c4)
```

or with gdb's internal printf command

```
printf "%s\n", 0xbffff0bf
```

or even by calling printf in your program under debug (if linked)

```
call printf("%8.3f\n",*(float*)(0xbffff194))
```

Likewise, using directly the string (I'll use argv[0]):

```
print argv[0]
"/home/asu..."
// assuming "/hom" was a proper address...
print **(int**)(argv[0]+0)
// assuming "e/as" was a proper address...
print **(int**)(argv[0]+4)
```

Comment: How is that readable - the octal stream is just as readable as hex stream but meaningless

Comment: It's much more readable. You can at least inspect the memory content pointed by these addresses in gdb. Quote : "What I'm really trying to get is the addresses that sscanf is saving to."

Comment: @Aki Suikhkonen, Is there any command to get those addresses from within GDB, or I have to open up another shell to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`args` is probably a [`va_list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_list/) (or an `_IO_va_list`?).  It's an opaque type, so it might be a trick to get gcc to tell you what's in it.  You could probably call its accessors to find out what the args are.